# Basic Auth Request in Swift

Tags: swift, post, swiftui, httprequest, basic-authentication

Hey so I'm relatively new to Swift and I have successfully fetched data from a public API but there's another one that requires authentication. I do have an account and I've verified that the credentials work, however it's not clear to me how to write the POST request with Basic Auth

I see on the Wiki page for Basic Auth it says to configure the URL with the user & pass in it like this: *https://Aladdin:OpenSesame@www.example.com/index.html*, but this alone doesn't fix it so I'm not sure what else I need to do to configure this request. Any help would be appreciated!

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var pool_system_type: String
}

struct WaterTestView: View {    
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.trackId) { result in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(result.pool_system_type)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myemail@email.com:mypassword@biolabhydra.com/api/v3/water_tests") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        results = decodedResponse.results
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible the API you trying to use doesn't use basic auth. Lots of apis have a `signIn` endpoint you need to call with the username and password as params and it will return a token. You then add the token to the header of your requests to get data from the API. The APIs docs should cover how to authenticate.

Comment: Hey! It does use Basic Auth. On the getting started page (https://www.biolabhydra.com/analysis/getting_started) it says "All Hydra requests must be made via https; any http request will be redirected to https. API requests are authenticated via HTTP Basic Authentication (username/password). Contact us to receive credentials."

Comment: That page requires signing in so I cant see it. It's possible they don't support URL encoding and you need to put the authorization in a header, which is also shown in the wiki article.

Answer (score 3):

For basic auth you put the authentication data in an HTTP header field.

```
extension URLRequest {
    mutating func setBasicAuth(username: String, password: String) {
        let encodedAuthInfo = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
            .data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            .base64EncodedString()
        addValue("Basic \(encodedAuthInfo)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
}

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.awesome.com/")!)
request.setBasicAuth(username: "awesomeUser", password: "awesomePass")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```